# Ajustes .bat que executa um .dstx

Tags: batch, ssis

Estou executando um arquivo .dtsx utilizando uma bat de carga e estou querendo fazer alguns ajustes:

1. Montar de maneira legível a data do nome do arquivo.
2. Ajustar no arquivo de log para que diga qual o nome do pacote .dtsx que foi executado
3. Diminuir o código para inserir data e hora no nome do arquivo de log.

Para gerar o nome do arquivo de log de erro é utilizado o seguinte código:

```
ECHO ON
:: DATA_HORA
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%

SET data=%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%%secs%

SET outputfile=%VAR_LOGS_DIR%CARGA_SSIS_%data%.log

"%VAR_DTSEXEC_DIR%" /F "%VAR_PACKAGE_DIR%\NOME_PACOTE.dtsx" /CONNECTION %CN_S_TRA% /CONNECTION %CN_T_STG%  /REPORTING E  >> %outputfile%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO END
```

O log gerado fica com o nome correto: `CARGA_SSIS_20170321_103029`, mas olhando p/ esse código que gera o nome indica que tem maneiras bem melhores de montar isso...

**Montar um log no arquivo que diga qual o nome do pacote .dtsx que foi executado:**

Eu preciso que ele informe no log qual o nome do pacote .dtsx que foi executado para resultar em sucesso/erro e que fosse removido alguns atributos que não são úteis, um exemplo de como eu queria que ficasse é o seguinte:

DO ORIGINAL:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.3487.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Started:  10:30:29
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:30:29
Finished: 10:31:47
Elapsed:  77.75 seconds

Started:  10:31:50
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:31:50
Finished: 10:32:47
Elapsed:  77.75 seconds

Started:  10:32:47
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:32:47
Finished: 10:34:43
Elapsed:  77.75 seconds
```

PARA O LOG COM O NOME DOS PACOTES .DTSX EXECUTADOS

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.3487.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Name: NOME_DO_PACOTE1.DTSX
Started:  10:30:29
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:30:29
Finished: 10:31:47
Elapsed:  77.75 seconds

Name: NOME_DO_PACOTE2.DTSX
Started:  10:31:50
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:31:50
Finished: 10:32:47
Elapsed:  77.75 seconds

Name: NOME_DO_PACOTE3.DTSX
Started:  10:32:47
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:32:47
Finished: 10:34:43
Elapsed:  77.75 seconds
```

Comment: As imagens estão inválidas, o que dificulta o entendimento da pergunta.

Comment: como assim? Aqui está tudo certo.....

Comment: Tem como colocar os exemplos em texto ao invés de imagem? Aqui o host das imagens é bloqueado, então não consigo ver.

Comment: Alterei para ter o texto

Comment: Qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 2):

Consigo te ajudar com sua terceira pergunta, para **diminuir o código que gera o nome do arquivo de log**. Pode substituir por:

```
:: Recebe a data com formatação padrão:
set data=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%
:: caso tiver espaço, troca para 0.
set data=%data: =0%
```

<sup>Fonte: [Format date and time in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

---

Sobre como fazer para obter **`data/hora`** da melhor forma e fazer uso para compor o layout
em **sub-string/variáveis/nome de arquivos**, sugiro consultar essa duas respostas
**[SO-pt/BR Q224040](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380175/131559) [SO-EN Q12635541](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637344/8177207)**, e mais esse **[post /EN](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/02/parsing-dates-in-batch-files-regional-settings-locale/)**

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && title <nul & title .\%~nx0

color 80 && for /f ^tokens^=^1^delims^=^. %%i in ('
%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime^|findstr [0-9]
')do set "_dt=%%~i" && call set "_data=!_dt:~0,4!!_dt:~4,2!!_dt:~6,2!_!_dt:~8,6!"

rem :: _Var !_dt! ==  20200124002435
rem :: ---------------------------------------------
rem :: !_dt:~0,4! ==  Ano 2020 
rem :: !_dt:~4,2! ==  Mes     01
rem :: !_dt:~6,2! ==  Dia       24
rem :: _          ==  Separador   _ 
rem :: !_dt:~8,6! ==  Hora (24/HH) 002435
rem :: -----------------------------------------------
rem :: Layout/Formato variavel _data: 20200124_012435 
rem :: !outputfile! == CARGA_SSIS_20200124_002435.log
rem :: -----------------------------------------------

SET "outputfile=!VAR_LOGS_DIR!CARGA_SSIS_!_data!.log"
echo/_dt=!_dt! # _data=!_data! # outputfile=!outputfile!

"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" -1

("!VAR_DTSEXEC_DIR!" /F "!VAR_PACKAGE_DIR!\NOME_PACOTE.dtsx" /CONNECTION !CN_S_TRA! /CONNECTION !CN_T_STG! /REPORTING E
)>>"!outputfile!" && (echo/ Comando executado sem erros^^!) || (start "" notepad.exe "!outputfile!")

endlocal && goto :END
```