# Como criar uma pasta com nome da data atual no cmd.exe do Windows

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, prompt

O que eu já tenho: `%date%` é a variável do windows que armazena a data atual. Quando eu uso `echo %date%` o valor `Tue 07/25/2017` é corretamente impresso.

Porém quando eu tento fazer `mkdir %date%` a pasta criada é `Tue 07` pois o windows não reconhece `/` como um caractere válido.

Como faço para contornar isso?

Comment: O formato de data deve ser Tue 07/25/2017 mesmo, ou só deve conter dia, mês e ano?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer coisa que dê para identificar a data tipo 07-25-2017, 25072017, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Update* Opção para executar uma linha:

O comando **`wmic OS Get localdatetime /value`**  retorna a string **`LocalDateTime=20190609123708.733000-180`**, usando 2 delimitadores, **`=.`**, obtemos **`20190609123708`**, dai usamos substring da saída para compor o layout para criar a pasta:

```cmd
%_data:~0,4%_%_data:~4,2%_%_data:~6,2%
   Ano:2019 _   Mês:06   _   Dia:09
```

---

No bat:

```cmd
@echo off & for /f "tokens=2delims==." %%i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value ^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_data=%%i" & call mkdir %_data:~0,4%_%_data:~4,2%_%_data:~6,2%
```

Na linha de comando:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=2delims==." %i in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value ^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_data=%i" & call mkdir %_data:~0,4%_%_data:~4,2%_%_data:~6,2%
```

---

O formato de data varia conforme: **região**, **idioma** e/ou **configurações feitas pelo usuário**

> **Referência:**
>
> [Safe way to get current day month and year in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635541/safe-way-to-get-current-day-month-and-year-in-batch)
>
> [Parsing Dates in Batch Files & Regional Settings / Locale](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/02/parsing-dates-in-batch-files-regional-settings-locale/)

---

A **variável** `%date%` vai sempre exibir a **data** no formato segundo **idioma** &
**país**, ou num formato **customizado/configurado pelo usuário**, ou seja, **não** segue layout/padrão fixo, onde podemos trabalhar de **forma preditiva**, e, consequentemente, manipular a string de saída, contando com um layout fixo/previsível

Sugiro usar o **`wmic`**, onde, **seguramente**, tens uma **saída padronizada** e independente de qualquer região, idioma e/ou qualquer configurações feitas pelo **usuário**.

**O comando:**

```cmd
wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Month,Year
```

Sempre retorna em looping for:

```cmd
[dia = 29 = %%a] [mês = 4 = %%b] [ano = 2019 = %%c]
```

Apos executar o comando:

```bat
wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Month,Year
```

Temos o resultado:

```bat
Day  Month  Year
29   4      2019 
%%a  %%b    %%c
```

---

Script **Dir_Date.cmd**:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "_do=wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year" 
for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('!_do!^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "y=%%c" & set "d=0%%a" & set "m=0%%b"
2>nul mkdir !y!!m:~-2!!d:~-2! >nul
```

---

**Obs.:** Em **PowerShell**, o layout pode ser personalizado com o  **`ToString("yyyyMMdd")`**, onde as opções permitem compor no layout desejado  apenas editando as **strings** com o **`ToString`**.

> **Exemplo:** **`yyyy-MM-dd, dd-MM-yyyy, MM-dd-yyyy, MM_dd_yyyy, yyyy_MM_dd, etc..`**

---

```bat
New-item -Name $(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") -ItemType directory
```

---

Answer (score 7):

Você não pode adicionar `/` no nome da pasta..
Você deve utilizar uma mascara para a data...
Normalmente é usado `YYYYMMDD` ou seja `ANO MES e DIA`, para ficar fácil a ordenação dos arquivos pela data...

Aqui tem um exemplo de como implementar...

```
set filedatetime=%date% // ou qualquer outra data
set filedatetime=%filedatetime:~6,4%%filedatetime:~3,2%%filedatetime:~0,2%
echo "%filedatetime%" //exemplo da saida... "20170725"
```

ai depois é só dar

```
mkdir %filedatetime%
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083653/6163123)

Comment: esse `:~6,4` funciona tipo uma função `substring`?

Comment: isto... por exemplo, o `%filedatetime:~6,4%`   está pegando a partir do 6 caractere, os 4 próximos, resumindo o 6 é o index e o 4 é o tamanho...

Answer (score 2):

Já que o requerimento é apenas mostrar a data toda, experimente:

```
mkdir %date:/=%
```

Answer (score 2):

Troque as barras por hifens adicionando **`:/=-`** depois de **`date`**

```
mkdir %date:/=-%
```